# how to fix "apache http server stopped working and was closed" error message of WampServer?

Tags: mysql, apache, message, wampserver

I would like to know how to fix the problem of "apache http server stopped working and was closed" error message of WampServer. I am using Vista as an operating System and I have installed WampServer 2.1 with the characteristics below:

Apache version:  2.2.17
PHP version: 5.3.5
MySQL version: 5.5.8

I have searched on internet about this bug and I found that the reason is mysql_close() syntax as you can notice on this link: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,52654,52832
. But what is strange is that I don't have such syntax error as you can notice in my code below:

```
    <?php
$a = $_REQUEST['subject1'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wkayetdb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, message FROM notifications WHERE subject = '".$a."' AND status = 'unseen' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");
$notification = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $message = $row['message'];
        if($message=="a ajouté"){
            $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT notifications.id AS id, groupe.id_groupe AS groupid, eventsgroupe.start AS startdate, groupe.groupename AS groupname, notifications.message AS message, eventsgroupe.title AS title, notifications.status as status FROM notifications, eventsgroupe, groupe WHERE notifications.actor = groupe.id_groupe AND notifications.object = eventsgroupe.id AND notifications.id = '".$id."'");
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                $notification = array('id'=>$row1['id'],'groupid'=>$row1['groupid'],'startdate'=>$row1['startdate'],'groupname'=>$row1['groupname'],'message'=>$row1['message'],'title'=>$row1['title'],'status'=>$row1['status']);
            }
        }
        elseif(($message=="a accepté votre invitation de rejoindre votre groupe")||($message=="a décliné votre invitation de rejoindre votre groupe")){
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT notifications.id AS id, groupe.groupename AS groupname, notifications.message AS message, user.name AS username FROM notifications, user, groupe WHERE notifications.actor = user.id_user AND  notifications.object = groupe.id_groupe AND notifications.id = '".$id."'");
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                $notification = array('id'=>$row2['id'],'username'=>$row2['username'],'message'=>$row2['message'],'groupname'=>$row2['groupname']);
            }
        }
}
echo json_encode($notification);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Just focus on the two lines: `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wkayetdb");` and `mysqli_close($con);`.

I really wonder what the problem is exactly, so is there anyone who has an idea about the solution?

Comment: Are you sure its being caused by this script? If you are what makes you think so? If you are sure, try removing lines of code until you identify the line that is causing the problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I didn't say that the script above was the cause of the problem, I was talking in general. Besides, I think that removing lines of code until I identify the line that is causing the problem won't be a useful solution as the other lines haven't any influence.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Have you tried freeing the statement handles before closing the connection? `mysql_free_result($result);` for all 3 statements. Or just leaving the `mysql_close()` out completely as this is done automatically by PHP when the script finishes anyway.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Well, I haven't really tried each one of these methods. But what is strange is that when I run the code above on another computer I don't have such problems. So it is obvious that the reason of the problem is the installed WampServer on my computer. By the way, I am running my application on a virtual machine.

Answer (score -1):

may be the problem is on your algorithm.

"while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))"

in this line use "=="  instead of "=".